# How to change the dataframe shape from multiple rows to a single row in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, reshape

I have this datafarme;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'image_id':'490.png', 'labels':['logo_sony', 'text', 'text', 'object_headphone', 'text', 'button']})
```

It returns a 6 rows and 2 columns dataframe.

```
   image_id   labels
0   490.png  logo_sony
1   490.png  text
2   490.png  text
3   490.png  object_headphone
4   490.png  text
5   490.png  button
```

How can I make it one row with two columns,like bellow

```
    image_id          labels
0   490.png         'logo_sony', 'text', 'text', 'object_headphone', 'text', 'button'
```

Thank you

Comment: Check out `groupby` and `.str.join` in documentation

Comment: tanx.  this line worked df.groupby(['image_id']).agg({'labels':','.join}). but how can I use the .str.join?

Comment: What you have done is correct. Just wanted to point you in the direction of string join. Glad that you found out on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the `list` in your input `dict` to a space separated `str` and read that in -

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({k: [' '.join(v)] if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for k, v in d.items()})
```

**Output**

```
  image_id                                            labels
0  490.png  logo_sony text text object_headphone text button
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use a string instead of a list as labels value:

```
labels = "'logo_sony', 'text', 'text', 'object_headphone', 'text', 'button'"
df = pd.DataFrame({'image_id':['490.png'], 'labels':labels})
print(df)
```

##### Output

```
  image_id                                             labels
0  490.png  'logo_sony', 'text', 'text', 'object_headphone...
```

Comment: Thank you. The labels are the outcome of a loop , some times I have too many of them and it would be hassle to type all.

Comment: use `", ".join(labels)` on the list and everything will work, by the way If one of the answers meets your needs, please extend the courtesy of accepting the answer.